# normalize css prevents style for single li

Tags: html, css, normalize-css

I am using a css reset, but ther is one list I want to have a list-style-type. How can I do this, the normalize is always reseting my styles.

[js fiddel code](http://jsfiddle.net/QRvhQ/)

at the end of the css, I'm trying to style the list by class, but is does not work.

HTML

```
    <ul class="disc">
                        <li>You can draw!</li>
                        <li>You can drag&drop Images!</li>
                        <li>You can add text labels!</li>
                    </ul>
```

css

```
.disc:li{
    list-style-type: disc;
}

.disc:ul{
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restore the original padding as well for those markers to show. For example:

```
ul.disc {
    list-style: disc;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QhJZb/).

This rule will be applied independent of whether `reset` rules are applied above or below it, as it's more [specific](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) (element selector + class) than `reset` ones (which never have classes, only element selectors + attribute selectors).

Answer (score 2):

You're using invalid CSS.
You should be using just the following:

```
ul.disc { 
  list-style: disc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the reset. There is a mistake in your code. It should be either this

```
.disc li{
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

or this

```
.disc {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

(You probably don't need both, but it depends on the reset.)

If the above doesn't work, then the rule needs to be more specific, such as adding a extra class or ID of the the container this list appears in.